# Drawing a train of arrows with tikz and foreach loops

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, foreach, loops

I am trying to draw a series of random arrows, each starting where the prior one ended, using tikz. I use polar coordinates and `remember`. From a logical standpoint, I feel like the following code should work. The end points of former arrows somehow don't match up with the starting point of the following arrows though...

The code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right]{$\ts{Re}(r)$};
\draw[-latex](0,-3) -- (0,3) node[above] {$\ts{Im}(r)$};

\def\r{0}
\def\t{0}

\foreach \z [remember=\r as \rlast (initially 0),remember=\t as \tlast (initially 0)] in {1,2,3,4,5,6}
  {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{random(0,360)};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\t}{0.01*random(0,100)};
    \draw[->] (\rlast:\tlast) -- ++ (\r:\t);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Remove `++` before the to-coordinate, since this draws a path to a coordinate that is relative to the first coordinate of the path. This won't work well with your setup. Also, you don't need to `\def` `\t` and `\r` beforehand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since named coordinates are stored globally:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right]{$\textrm{Re}(r)$};
\draw[-latex](0,-3) -- (0,3) node[above] {$\textrm{Im}(r)$};

\coordinate (last) at (0,0);

\foreach \z in {1,2,3,4,5,6}
  {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{random(0,360)};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\t}{0.01*random(0,100)};
    \draw[->] (last) -- ++ (\r:\t) coordinate (last);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

With `++(x,y)` (or `+(x,y)`) you define a coordinate that is relative to the previous coordinate (which means that in `\draw (1,1) -- ++(1,1);` the second coordinate of this path is essentially `({1+1},{1+1})` or `(2,2)`). In your setup, this will not yield the intended result, because you store `\r` as `\rlast` and `\t` as `\tlast` but you draw to `({\r+\rlast},{\t+\tlast})`. Thus, the second coordinate of a path is never the same as the first coordinate of the following path. Remove the `++`, and you will be fine (I enlarged the values for `\t` a bit):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {$\textrm{Re}(r)$};
\draw[-latex] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[above] {$\textrm{Im}(r)$};

\foreach \z [
    remember=\r as \rlast (initially 0), 
    remember=\t as \tlast (initially 0)
] in {1,2,3,4,5,6} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{random(0,360)};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\t}{0.03*random(0,100)};
    \draw[->] (\rlast:\tlast) -- (\r:\t);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You don't need to define `\t` and `\r` beforehand, because Ti*k*Z will define them on the fly.

[image]

---

If you need the second coordinate of every path to be relative to the first, you need to do the calculation in such a way, that `\r` and `\t` get the calculated relative values, so that these values will be stored in `\rlast` and `\tlast`. If you do the calculation on the coordinate directly (for example using `\draw[->] (\rlast:\tlast) -- ({\r+\rlast}:{\t+\tlast});`), you have again the same problem like in your original question. So, I think, this should also work for you:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {$\textrm{Re}(r)$};
\draw[-latex] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[above] {$\textrm{Im}(r)$};

\foreach \z [
    remember=\r as \rlast (initially 0), 
    remember=\t as \tlast (initially 0)
] in {1,2,3,4,5,6} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{random(0,360)+\rlast};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\t}{0.01*random(0,100)+\tlast};
    \draw[->] (\rlast:\tlast) -- (\r:\t);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: hanks for your answer. I need the coordinates to be relative to the prior ones though, otherwise I won't connect random arrows but rather connect random points (with polar coordinates) with each other, right? So what if I used \draw[->] (\rlast:\tlast) -- ($(\r:\t)+(\rlast:\tlast)$); ?

Comment: @manuel459 But then again, the coordinate stored in `\rlast` and `\tlast` won't be right. You need to store the second coordinate as last coordinate, this is crucial.

Comment: @manuel459 Also, since the points are already random, what is the difference between adding one random value to another and just using a single random value without addition (except that in the first case, the next value will always be greater than the former, while this might not always be true in the second case)? It really depends on what you want to achieve. Anyways, you need to make sure that `\rlast` is really the `\r` (and `\tlast` the `\t`) of the last loop and that you use only these values for the coordinates of the arrows. Otherwise the arrows will not be connected.

Answer (score 4):

Both the `chains` library and the `graphs` library can help you make that a bit less manual.

The `random polar shift` keys will place the next coordinate in relation to the previous coordinate (red) while `random polar placement` will place the coordinates absolutely (blue).

### Code (chains)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains}
\tikzset{
  random polar shift/.style={    at=(\tikzchainprevious),
                              shift={({random(0,360)}:{random(0,#1)})}},
  random polar placement/.style={at={({random(0,360)}:{random(0,#1)})}}}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetseed{20230330}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  start chain=ps going {random polar shift     = 100},
  start chain=pp going {random polar placement = 300},
  every join/.append style={->, shorten >=2\pgflinewidth}]
\draw[-Latex] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right]{$\textrm{Re}(r)$};
\draw[-Latex] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[above]{$\textrm{Im}(r)$};
\path[x=+.1mm, y=+.1mm] foreach \z in {1,...,6} {
   coordinate[on chain=ps, join=by red]
   coordinate[on chain=pp, join=by blue]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Code (graphs)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, graphs.standard}
\tikzgraphsset{
  random polar shift/.style={group shift={({random(0,360)}:{random(0,#1)})}},
  random polar shift/.default=100,
  random polar placement/.style={nodes={at={({random(0,360)}:{random(0,#1)})}}},
  random polar placement/.default=100}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetseed{30032023}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-Latex] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right]{$\textrm{Re}(r)$};
\draw[-Latex] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[above]{$\textrm{Im}(r)$};
\path[x=+.1mm, y=+.1mm, shorten >=2\pgflinewidth,
  graphs/every graph/.append style={path, ->, nodes=coordinate}]
  graph[edges=red,  random polar shift        ] {              subgraph I_n [n=6] }
  graph[edges=blue, random polar placement=300] { 0[x=0, y=0], subgraph I_n [n=5] };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output (chains/graph)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For comparison, here is a version in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html).

[image]

This is wrapped up in `luamplib` so you need to compile it with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
% a function to turn a <path> into a <picture> of the path draw with arrows
vardef with_arrows expr p = image(
    interim ahangle := 20;
    for i=1 upto length p:
        drawarrow subpath(i-1, i) of p 
            cutafter fullcircle scaled 3 shifted point i of p; % shorten the arrow slightly
    endfor) 
enddef;
beginfig(1);
    % axes
    path xx, yy;
    xx = (left--right) scaled 150;
    yy = xx rotated 90;
    
    % paths for the chains of arrows
    path chain[];  
    chain1 = origin for i=1 upto 12: .. uniformdeviate 144 * dir uniformdeviate 360 endfor;
    chain2 = origin for i=1 upto 12: -- uniformdeviate 144 * dir uniformdeviate 360 endfor;
    % note the different connectors -- for straight, .. for free

    % two pictures for comparison
    picture P[];
    P1 = image(
        drawarrow xx;
        drawarrow yy;
        draw with_arrows chain1 withcolor 1/2 blue;
    );
    P2 = image(
        drawarrow xx;
        drawarrow yy;
        draw with_arrows chain2 withcolor 1/2 red;
    );

    % show the pictures side-by-side
    draw P1; draw P2 shifted 320 right;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

### Notes

- to get the point `rθ` in MP you write `r * dir theta` with `theta` in degrees.
- to get a random point anywhere in a circle with radius 144 pt you can write `uniformdeviate 144 * dir uniformdeviate 360`
- `uniformdeviate` takes a single undelimited numeric argument and returns a random real number between 0 and the given number.
- You could keep track of a current point and draw arrows to the next point as you generated them, but I thought it was neater to capture all the points in a `<path>` variable.
- The `with_arrows` macro then takes that `<path>` and returns a `<picture>` of the path drawn with arrows (with thin arrowheads and little gaps).
- I think I prefer the version with the curly path.